# make quickwidget background transparent

Tags: qt, qquickwidget

I have created 2 `QWidget` and 1 `QQuickWidget` in main window. The `QQuickWidget` uses a source qml file. I want to set background transparent for two `QWidget`s and the `QQuickWidget`.

Can anyone help me to make the background of the `QQuickWidget` transparent so that my main window is also visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const auto m_QuickWidgetPtr = new QQuickWidget(this);
    ...
    m_QuickWidgetPtr->setAttribute( Qt::WA_AlwaysStackOnTop );
    m_QuickWidgetPtr->setAttribute( Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground );
    m_QuickWidgetPtr->setClearColor( Qt::transparent );
```